# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am Registering a user in the User_Auth Database, but I got CSRF_tokens error...
The data submitted in the in built User database of Django

register.html

```
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 " align="center" style="margin:50px;">
                <h3>Register for an Account</h3>
                    <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{form.errors}}
                        <table>
                            <tr><td>Username:<input type="text"  value=""name="username"></td></tr><br>
                            <tr><td>Password: <input type="password" value=""name="password"></td></tr>
                            <!--Superuser:<select>-->
                                <!--<option value="0" name="is_superuser">0</option>-->
                                <!--<option value="1" name="is_superuser">1</option>-->
                            <!--</select>-->
                        </table>
                        <div align="center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Submit</button></div>
                    </form>
            </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    form = UserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.create(
            username = form.cleaned_data['username'],
            password = form.cleaned_data['password'],
        )
        user.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('signin')
else:
    form=UserForm()
return render(request, 'customer/register.html', {'form': form})
```

here is my
forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
```

Comment: And you still getttings this error after you change csrf_input?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
{{ csrf_input }}
```

to

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

Comment: make sure you have the token inside {%, not {{ otherwise it is treated as a variable, not a template tag.

Comment: And refresh the page. Look at the html output that is sent to the browser (right click, inspect element), and check that it is actually getting parsed and putting the token there.